# How to iterate arraylists within an arraylist, and insert their data onto an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Let's say I have an array that takes instances of the type "Pessoal":

```
Pessoal[] teste = new Pessoal[6];
```

Now let's say I have 2 arraylists that are inside of an arraylist:

```
static ArrayList<Pessoal> lista_de_profs; // This one has 4

static ArrayList<Pessoal> lista_de_infos; // And this one has 2, matching the 6 on "teste"

// these arrayslists have instances of the type "Pessoal"
```

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Pessoal>> lista_de_docentes = new ArrayList<>();
 
lista_de_docentes.add(lista_de_profs); 
lista_de_docentes.add(lista_de_infos);
```

---

How do I iterate through the arraylist (lista_de_docentes) that contains more arraylists (lista_de_profs & lista_de_infos), and get their instances, so I can put them inside the array?

This works if teste's length is 4

```
for (int i = 0; i < teste.length; i++){
     teste[i] = lista_de_profs.get(i);
}
```

But this only covers one arraylist, and I want all of the ones inside "lista_de_docentes", which are: "lista_de_profs" and "lista_de_infos"

*Some code in here, the language is in Portuguese, but I can change it to english, if it becomes confusing.

I hope I was clear, and thanks.

Comment: using stream api `Pessoal[] result = lista_de_docentes.stream().flatMap(ArrayList::stream).toArray(Pessoal[]::new);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Pessoal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Pessoal> lista_de_profs = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Pessoal> lista_de_infos = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Pessoal>> lista_de_docentes = new ArrayList<>();
        lista_de_docentes.add(lista_de_profs); 
        lista_de_docentes.add(lista_de_infos);
        Pessoal[] teste = lista_de_docentes.stream()
                                           .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                           .toArray(new Pessoal[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(teste));
    }
}
```

- `lista_de_docentes.stream()` creates a stream where every element has type `ArrayList<Pessoal>`.
- `flatMap` returns a stream where every element has type `Pessoal`.
- All the stream [`Pessoal`] elements are collected and put into a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).
- Method [toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) (of interface `List`) converts the `List` to an array.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use streams:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Pessoal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Pessoal> lista_de_profs = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Pessoal> lista_de_infos = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Pessoal>> lista_de_docentes = new ArrayList<>();
        lista_de_docentes.add(lista_de_profs); 
        lista_de_docentes.add(lista_de_infos);
        ArrayList<Pessoal> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ArrayList<Pessoal> list : lista_de_docentes) {
            for (Pessoal p : list) {
                temp.add(p);
            }
        }
        Pessoal[] teste = new Pessoal[temp.size()];
        temp.toArray(teste);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(teste));
    }
}
```

By the way, you should consider adopting [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Hey, your answer worked as well, so thanks.

And thanks for the naming convesntions link.

Answer (score 3):

You can collect all your "Pessoal" elements into a single arraylist and then move the elements to your array

```
List<Pessoal> all= lista_de_docentes.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (int i =0; i < all.size(); i++)
    teste[i] = all.get(i);
```

Or you can directly create the array (in case you don't care about the size)

```
Pessoal[] teste = lista_de_docentes.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toArray(Pessoal[]::new);
```

Comment: I have tried all solutions in this post so far, and yours also works, so thanks.